# USB Modem changed IPV4 route table Metric of LAN to 4237 windows 7

Tags: networking, windows-7, routes, network-interface

I am using two network interfaces (Below).

Scenario 1:
Initially LAN is connected with metric=12 of ipv4 route table.

```
    IPv4 Route Table
    ===========================================================================
    Active Routes:

    Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
             0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0        10.12.1.2       10.12.1.13     12
            10.12.1.0    255.255.255.0         On-link        10.12.1.13    262
           10.12.1.13  255.255.255.255         On-link        10.12.1.13    262
          10.12.1.255  255.255.255.255         On-link        10.12.1.13    262
            127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
            127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
      127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
            224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
            224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link        10.12.1.13    262
      255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
      255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link        10.12.1.13    262
    ===========================================================================
```

LAN ip 10.12.1.13.

When USB Modem gets connected to the system, it changed the LAN metric to 4237. and USB modem gets the metric lower value between 4-10.

```
    IPv4 Route Table
    ===========================================================================
    Active Routes:
    Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
              0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0        10.12.1.2       10.12.1.13   4237
              0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0         On-link    101.63.220.237      6
            10.12.1.0    255.255.255.0         On-link        10.12.1.13   4487
           10.12.1.13  255.255.255.255         On-link        10.12.1.13   4487
          10.12.1.255  255.255.255.255         On-link        10.12.1.13   4487
       101.63.220.237  255.255.255.255         On-link    101.63.220.237    261
            127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1   4531
            127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1   4531
      127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1   4531
            224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1   4531
            224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link        10.12.1.13   4488
            224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link    101.63.220.237      6
      255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1   4531
      255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link        10.12.1.13   4487
      255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link    101.63.220.237    261
    ===========================================================================
```

LAN IP :      10.12.1.13          4237 (Metric)
USB Modem IP: 101.63.220.237      6     (Metric)

Now the default network interface is USB Modem because it has lowest value of Metric.

Problem: Now my local application is able to connect with default network interface (Metric-6) but cant connect with LAN network interface to access internet (Metric-4237).

Scenario 2:
I changed the metric of LAN from 4237 to 12 (or any value lower value or near value to default network interface), then my local application is able to connect with LAN as well.

```
    IPv4 Route Table
    ===========================================================================
    Active Routes:
    Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
              0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0         On-link    101.63.220.237      6
              0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0        10.12.1.2       10.12.1.13     12
            10.12.1.0    255.255.255.0         On-link        10.12.1.13    262
           10.12.1.13  255.255.255.255         On-link        10.12.1.13    262
          10.12.1.255  255.255.255.255         On-link        10.12.1.13    262
       101.63.220.237  255.255.255.255         On-link    101.63.220.237    261
            127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1   4531
            127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1   4531
      127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1   4531
            224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1   4531
            224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link    101.63.220.237      6
            224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link        10.12.1.13    262
      255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1   4531
      255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link    101.63.220.237    261
      255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link        10.12.1.13    262
    ===========================================================================
```

Persistent Routes:

Queries:

1. What is metric range (min-max)?
2. Why application is not able to connect with LAN when its metric value is 4237?

Please suggest the correct way to use metric?